# Vagrant SSH's fine but Ansible is unable to ping (it's unable to SSH)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

Here is my Vagrantfile.

```
$ cat Vagrantfile 
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "debian/stretch64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = "4096"
  end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

I am able to create and SSH into this machine.

```
$ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'debian/stretch64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) wlo1
2) eno1
==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
    default: Which interface should the network bridge to? 1
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest
    default: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host only
    default: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    default: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    default: 
    default: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work properly,
    default: in which case you may ignore this message.
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /home/ashim/Documents/ansible-project/ => /vagrant
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default: 
==> default: Vanilla Debian box. See https://app.vagrantup.com/debian for help and bug reports
```

I enquire the IP address of the VM.

```
$ vagrant ssh
Linux stretch 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian   4.9.168-1+deb9u2 (2019-05-13) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux   system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program   are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO  WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Sep 15 15:05:58 2019 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@stretch:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd  00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu  1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen  1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8d:c0:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:c04d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:22:65:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.101/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe22:6555/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
vagrant@stretch:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
$
```

Here is my inventory list for ansible:-

```
$ cat custom-hosts 
[only-host]
192.168.1.101 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

When I run the ping module,it crashes! Why is this ?

```
    $ ansible only-host -i custom-hosts -m ping
192.168.1.101 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via   ssh: vagrant@192.168.1.101: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ansible ping module is not doing a literal "ping" command, it's actually a really basic [python script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/ping.py)

This means it's testing a few things:

- is the IP reachable
- can your Ansible user succesfully SSH
- is a suitable Python installation present

In your case the error is:

> "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via   ssh: vagrant@192.168.1.101: Permission denied (publickey)

This means you can reach the IP but the user is not allowed to log in. You're probably using a different SSH key than what Vagrant is using.

Comment: Can you please show me how to use the correct key ? I am new to this.

Comment: Hi, when I created a new user and created SSH keys for it/ added the keys to the same user's authorized_keys in the VM, it SSHed fine. It seems to me that the default insecure_private_key is not used automatically in the above example. That is why it won't SSH.Is there a reason that the default insecure_private_key is not used automatically?

Comment: you mentioned an important point:"The Ansible ping module is not doing a literal "ping" command, it's actually a really basic python script"